# How to generate last date of every month between two dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, postgresql-8.2

I want to generate a list of last date of every month between two dates.
For example, i want to generate

From `2004-01-31`
to `2005-08-31`
and the result should be like this

```
2004-01-31
2004-02-29
2004-03-31
2004-04-30
2004-05-31
.
.
.
2005-07-31
2005-08-31
```

Can anyone help me how to do it and got that result in PostgreSQL? Thanks! Im using postgreSQL 8.2.15

Comment: Try https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-srf.html and function `generate_series`

Comment: @Kadet in version 8.2 generate_series can only used with int...

Comment: @Kadet can i use function generate_series with date? As long as i know argument type in that function is int or big int. That function cant even handle numeric type in my version

Comment: AFAIK; there is no function like "LastDay" or similar in Postgres, but to get the last day of the month, you can do something like "SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ('202205'||'10')::date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::DATE;"  which means take the first day of the month, add one month and then substract one day.

Comment: Display last day each month of year .. SELECT (date_trunc('month', '2017-01-05'::date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date
AS end_of_month;

Comment: @Jonas Metzler yes, but can i generate ALL lastdate or lastday of every month between two dates?

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select to_date('2004-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD') + (dates*interval '1 month')
from generate_series(0,19,1) dates
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate how many months are between start date and end date and then build a list of start date + 1 month as long as the end date is not reached:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2004-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD') + (d*INTERVAL '1 MONTH')
FROM generate_series(0,(SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age
(TO_DATE('2005-08-31','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2004-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))) * 12 +
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age(TO_DATE('2005-08-31','YYYY-MM-DD'), 
TO_DATE('2004-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))) AS INT)),1) d
```